# Runtime error '1004'; Method 'Intersect' of object '_Application' failed

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim checkRange As Range

    ' Set source and destination sheets
    Set sourceSheet = Sheet2 ' The sheet where the change occurred
    Set destinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5") ' Replace with the destination sheet name

    ' Define a check range (adjust as needed)
    Set checkRange = sourceSheet.UsedRange

    ' Check if the changed cells intersect with the check range
     If Not Application.Intersect(Target, checkRange) Is Nothing Then
        ' Find the last used row in the destination sheet
        lastRow = destinationSheet.Cells(destinationSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        ' Copy the entire row to the destination sheet
        sourceSheet.Rows(Target.Row).Copy destinationSheet.Rows(lastRow)

        ' Optional: Clear the contents in the source sheet after transfer
        ' sourceSheet.Rows(Target.Row).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

I expect that every time the user enter a new data then it will automatically detect and pass it to the destination spreadsheet so it may reduce the user to reenter again the same data

Comment: Why do you use `Set sourceSheet = Sheet2` on one line, and `Set destinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")` on the next one? Shouldn't they both use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets`?

Comment: The error is occurring because `Intersect` doesn't work with ranges on different worksheets. At the moment, `checkRange` is a range on the sheet with the codename `Sheet2`. If you change a cell in any other worksheet the error will occur. Even if you change a cell value on `Sheet2`, the error will still occur after writing to the sheet with the tabname `Sheet5` because you haven't disabled events and the code is triggered again. Most probably, you have chosen the wrong event for your desired operation. Please share in detail what you're trying to achieve and when.

Comment: i want to achieve the excel file that can be link. For example, if i enter the $10.20 in credit side then should it possible to pass the data to the other page that required this data to do further accounting purpose

Comment: Of course, it is possible but you need to share your complete idea (plan). We know you want to track changes on `Sheet2` and at some point copy a row to `Sheet5` but we don't know when. I mean, if you enter in `A2` and copy the row and then enter in `B2` and copy the row it doesn't make sense. You have to decide when, e.g. if you enter `Yes` in column `C` then copy, or if you enter in columns A:D and all columns are not empty then copy. if you would share a screenshot of your worksheet(s) it may be easier to explain what you're trying to do. You can always edit your question to add more info.

Comment: okay, i am actually doing what you give the example which is after i enter in columns A until F check if no empty then it will copy the row to the Sheet5

Answer (score 0):

**Sheet Module `Sheet2`, NOT `ThisWorkbook` module**

- Create a copy of your workbook and test the code there since you haven't shared enough information and I still can only guess what your data looks like.
- Delete the code that you have in the `ThisWorkbook` module and copy this code to the `Sheet2` module.
- If any cell in columns `A:F` is changed, the code automatically checks if all cells in the cell's row are not blank and if so, copies the (entire) row to sheet `Sheet5`.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const TARGET_COLUMNS As String = "A:F"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet5"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "A" ' must be `A` if entire rows are copied!
    
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = Target.Worksheet
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = tws.UsedRange.Columns(TARGET_COLUMNS)
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(trg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Set irg = Intersect(irg.EntireRow, tws.Columns(TARGET_COLUMNS))
    
    Dim urg As Range, irrg As Range
    
    For Each irrg In irg.Rows
        If Application.CountBlank(irrg) = 0 Then
            If urg Is Nothing Then
                Set urg = irrg
            Else
                Set urg = Union(urg, irrg)
            End If
        End If
    Next irrg
    
    If urg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = tws.Parent.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim dfcell As Range:
    With dws.UsedRange
        Set dfcell = dws.Cells(.Row + .Rows.Count, DST_COLUMN)
    End With
    
    urg.Copy dfcell
    ' or, if there is data to the right of 'A:F' that needs to be copied ???
    'urg.EntireRow.Copy dfcell

End Sub
```